# Template builder error while executing the Template-Session id unknown

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, template-builder

I am getting the below error while executing template builder for page template.

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Internal error: Session id 'a64a9700-0a73-4963-936c-143bcd1e6529' is unknown

at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Proxy.CompoundTemplateWebService.GetDebuggingState(String debuggerSessionId, String lastLogMessageId)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.DebugObject.Start(Template template, Object debugItem, LoggingOptions loggingOptions)

I am using Template Builder 7.1 for Tridion 2013 SP1.

Can you please help me to resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the same issue when our system is load balanced. You will need to connect to a particular node of your Content Manager when using TB. Otherwise your session changes to your other node, and then you get this error. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting Template Builder?
Have you tried running an IIS reset?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I did all above steps still issue exists